# JSON array deserialization is crashing the Dalvik VM

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have some code grabbing a JSON array from my server and initially storing it as a string. This all works fine until I try and deserialize it using google's gson fromJson method. LogCat spits out the error:

`04-08 17:46:35.163: ERROR/dalvikvm(401): Can't shrink stack: curFrame is in reserved area (0x41049000 0x410491c4)`

My code that causes the error is:

`String[] results = gson.fromJson(returnString, String[].class);`

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the following open issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6245.

> The stack is supposed to expand briefly while the StackOverflowError is
>   being handled, then shrink back down afterward.  The problem is that an exception is
>   being thrown during the SOE processing, and we're trying to shrink the stack down
>   when that second exception finishes, instead of waiting until we're wrapping up the
>   SOE itself.
>
> There's also enough going on during the SOE recovery that an extra 512 bytes of stack
>   isn't enough, and it'll encounter a double-SOE.

How large is the JSON that you are trying to de-serialize?